# how to select data from multiple tables in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

[image]

any solution? both tables have the same field name.

```
<?php
class New_post extends Ci_model{

    function __construct()
     {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
     }

     public function get_user_data()
     {
      $this->load->library('session'); 

        $user_id=$this->session->userdata('login_id');
        $this->load->database();
       $query=$this->db->select(['First_Name','Last_Name',' Mobile_Number','bio'])
                     -> from('employ','jobseekers')
                     ->where('login_id',$user_id)
                     ->get();
                     return $query->result();
```

Comment: [please format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use join the 2 tables by.

**$this->db->join();**

Permits you to write the `JOIN portion` of your query:-

```
function get_user_data()
{
       $this->load->library('session'); 
       $user_id=$this->session->userdata('login_id');
       $this->load->database();
        
    $this->db->select('*')
    $this->db->from('employ');
    $this->db->join('jobseekers','employ.login_id=jobseekers.login_id');
    $this->db->where('employ.login_id',$user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

**For More info regarding this:-**

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Join :-

```
    $this->db->select('table1.First_Name,table1.Last_Name,table1.Mobile_Number,table2.First_Name,table2.Last_Name,table2.Mobile_Number');
    $this->db->from('table1');
    $this->db->join('table2', 'table2.common_id= table1.common_id', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->get()->result();
```

Where (common_id) is the foreign Key which is common in both tables